# How to use productsign with mpkg containing smaller signed pkg files?

Tags: macos, code-signing, osx-gatekeeper, mpkg, productsign

I have a parent installer package, say, called `Parent.unsigned.mpkg` that I would like to sign with OS X `productsign`.

The file `Parent.unsigned.mpkg` contains children packages called `A.pkg`, `B.pkg` and `C.pkg`, which in turn install Clang-compiled command-line binaries and `bash` wrapper scripts:

```
./Parent.unsigned.mpkg/Contents/Packages/A.pkg
./Parent.unsigned.mpkg/Contents/Packages/B.pkg
./Parent.unsigned.mpkg/Contents/Packages/C.pkg
```

I signed up for a Mac Developer account, which sets up (among other certificates) a Developer ID Installer certificate with the ID `ABCD1234` (this ID is actually different and specific to my Apple ID.) I obtain this ID value using the `security` tool:

```
$ security find-certificate -a -c "Developer ID Installer" | grep "alis"
    "alis"<blob>="Developer ID Installer: Foo B. Baz (ABCD1234)"
```

I sign each of these children packages with this ID value, which appears to proceed without incident:

```
$ productsign --timestamp --sign ABCD1234 ./Parent.unsigned.mpkg/Contents/Packages/A.pkg ./Parent.unsigned.mpkg/Contents/Packages/A.signed.pkg
...
$ productsign --timestamp --sign ABCD1234 ./Parent.unsigned.mpkg/Contents/Packages/B.pkg ./Parent.unsigned.mpkg/Contents/Packages/B.signed.pkg
...
$ productsign --timestamp --sign ABCD1234 ./Parent.unsigned.mpkg/Contents/Packages/C.pkg ./Parent.unsigned.mpkg/Contents/Packages/C.signed.pkg
...
```

I then move these signed children packages back to their original filenames:

```
$ mv ./Parent.unsigned.mpkg/Contents/Packages/A.signed.pkg ./Parent.unsigned.mpkg/Contents/Packages/A.pkg
$ mv ./Parent.unsigned.mpkg/Contents/Packages/B.signed.pkg ./Parent.unsigned.mpkg/Contents/Packages/B.pkg
$ mv ./Parent.unsigned.mpkg/Contents/Packages/C.signed.pkg ./Parent.unsigned.mpkg/Contents/Packages/C.pkg
```

When I try to `productsign` the parent package, I get the following warning messages:

```
$ productsign --timestamp --sign ABCD1234 ./Parent.unsigned.mpkg ./Parent.signed.mpkg
productsign: preparing "Parent.unsigned.mpkg" for signing ...
productsign: Using timestamp authority for signature
productsign: warning: component package "A.pkg" not found inside "Parent.unsigned.mpkg" and must be signed explicitly
productsign: warning: component package "B.pkg" not found inside "Parent.unsigned.mpkg" and must be signed explicitly
productsign: warning: component package "C.pkg" not found inside "Parent.unsigned.mpkg" and must be signed explicitly
productsign: Wrote signed product archive to ./Parent.signed.mpkg
```

When I try to verify that the installer is signed, I get a rejection message:

```
$ spctl -a -v --type install ./Parent.signed.mpkg 
./Parent.signed.mpkg: rejected
```

I am using Apple's directions outlined [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingApplicationsOutside/DistributingApplicationsOutside.html) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/productsign.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/productsign).

The unsigned installer works correctly as it is, but it requires bypassing OS X Gatekeeper. So the installer bundle and contents appear to be correct (or at least working correctly).

What steps or procedures am I missing that generate a digitally-signed installer that works with OS X Gatekeeper?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used `Packages.app` to create the package project.

Within `Packages.app`, I changed the project type from `Bundle` to `Flat` and rebuilt the Installer archive.

I then proceeded with the `productsign` steps via command line as described above, except that I only need to sign the parent `pkg` file to generate a working, signed Installer (I did not sign the children packages).

Using `pkgutil --flatten` to try to flatten the `mpkg` bundle output on the command-line ended up corrupting the Installer — I had to change the project type from `Bundle` to `Flat` within `Packages.app` and rebuild the Installer within that application, and sign the flat Installer file outside `Packages.app`.

Comment: I also try to sign my.pkg file and have next error 'An installer signing identity (not an application signing identity) is required for signing flat-style products'. In Packages.app I setup project format as "Flat" Help please

Comment: Sounds like you need to use an installer certificate to sign the installer. An application certificate would be for an application, not an installer. You'd need to log into your Apple Developer account and make/download an installer certificate.

Comment: https://www.evernote.com/l/AS24Migyho5PIqf4GVBuYwBsoyScDdeWh3Q
Here we can se that 'Developer Id' also use for installer package. Here I create a post, look please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47149047/codesigning-pkg-file-which-contain-other-pkg-files/47150016#47150016