# CodeSigning pkg file which contain other pkg files

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

For creating `.pkg` file I use '**Packager.app**'. I create project with **Format - 'Flat'**. When I try to sign `.pkg` file with next command

`productsign --sign "Developer ID Application: Tomas Urbonavicius (99ZZ8796S2)" my.pkg  my_signed.pkg`

I have next error '**Could not find appropriate signing identity for “Developer ID Application: Tomas Urbonavicius (99ZZ8796S2)”. An installer signing identity (not an application signing identity) is required for signing flat-style products**'.

If I create project with **Format - 'Bundle'**, I have output file format '**.mpkg**'. When I try to sign **.mpkg**, I have next error

'**component package "saver.pkg" not found inside "my.mpkg" and must be signed explicitly,
component package "app.pkg" not found inside "my.mpkg" and must be signed explicitly**'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, you need to use an installer signing identity, not an application signing identity. It should be named "Developer ID Installer: Tomas Urbonavicius (99ZZ8796S2)". If you don't have an installer identity, you may need to generate one. See Apple's doc on [Maintaining Your Signing Identities and Certificates](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html) for info on how to do this.